# CSS accordion menu, doesn't work in IE Quirks mode

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, menu, accordion

Here's what I'm working with:

```html
<style>
    html {
  background:#4d4d4d;
}

#accordion .item {
    width: 194px;
    max-height: 33px;
    background:lightsalmon;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    transition: max-height .5s;
    -o-transition: max-height .5s;
    -moz-transition: max-height .5s;
    -webkit-transition: max-height .5s;
}

#accordion a {
    display:block;
    height:auto;
    width:184px;
    line-height:33px;
    padding-left:10px;
    color:#000000;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#accordion .item:hover {
    max-height:396px; /* Set to height of the longest sub-menu for best results */
}

#accordion .item a:hover {
    background:#FF3333;
    -o-transition: .3s;
    -ms-transition: .3s;
    -moz-transition: .3s;
    -webkit-transition: .3s;
    transition: .3s;
}


#accordion .item:hover {
    max-height:396px; /* Set to height of the longest sub-menu for best results */
}

.sub {
    *padding-left:20px !important;
    *overflow:hidden;
    background:#ffffff;
    color:#000000;
    *height:auto !important;
    font-weight:normal !important;
}

</style>

<div id="accordion">
    <div class="item" id="brakes">
    <a href="#">Menu 1</a>
        <a href="#" class="sub">Submenu 1</a>
        <a href="#" class="sub">Submenu 2</a>
        <a href="#" class="sub">Submenu 3</a>
        <a href="#" class="sub">Submenu 4</a>
        <a href="#" class="sub">Submenu 5</a>
        <a href="#" class="sub">Submenu 6</a>
        <a href="#" class="sub">Submenu 7</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that it doesn't work in IE Quirks mode, and I need it to work in quirks, because of how eBay product listings work.

I thought I could set the css by using jQuery, however it doesn't seem to work, here's my attempt:

```html
<script>
    $('.item').hover(function(){
        $(this).css('max-height','396px');
    });
</script>
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Or a better solution maybe?

Comment: I found the problem, I had inserted the code at the top of the page, before all the elements, once I moved the snippet down to the bottom of the html code, it works.

Answer (score 1):

You're using transitions, which is a CSS3 element only supported as of IE10...

You'll need to use an external library like [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/), which detects and also adds features missing in certain browsers...

Also see [here](http://joshemerson.co.uk/blog/using-jquery-as-a-fallback-for-css3-transitions) for a workaround...

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but the transition effects aren't that important to me, I am just trying to expand the menu (max-height) by using javascript instead of css